# How to share config across multiple Node.js Lambda functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS serverless application building. How can I share global config data across multiple Lambda function written in Node.js.

Comment: what does the config data you want to share include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For configuration, consider:

1. JSON (or other) properties files packaged with the Lambda functions
2. environment variables configured on the Lambda functions

If you really need a common persistent source of configuration so that Lambdas do not need to be re-deployed when a configuration change happens, then consider:

1. Parameter Store
2. DynamoDB

Answer (score 1):

For lambda configuration, use AWS Lambda Environment Variables:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html

If you want same config for multiple lambdas use DynamoDB or any other storage.